# Sql Compact 3.5: Limit number of rows in column

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a table with rows of the following form: Timestamp Data:
I would like to keep only newest N rows in table, and delete everything rest.

Is there a way to specify deletion of all except N newest rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from table 
where id not in (
    select top 30 id from table
    order by timestampcolumn desc
)
```

Here `N = 30`. You can replace the number 30 by any number you want to retain.